# First 30 values per key in dict with lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary.

```
{'VVD': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male'], 'PVV (Partij voor de Vrijheid)': ['male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male']}
```

I want to get the first 30 values per key. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
dct = {'VVD': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male'], 'PVV (Partij voor de Vrijheid)': ['male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'male']}

for key in dct:
    print(dct[key][:30])
```

Or, if you want them in a list, you can use a [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/):

```
lst = [dct[key][:30] for key in dct]
```

If you don't want the list to be a nested list, you can use a nested list comprehension:

```
lst = [val for key in dct for val in dct[key][:30]]
```

If you want to keep the dictionary:

```
dct = {key: val[:30] for key, val in dct.items()}
```

or

```
dct = {key: dct[key][:30] for key in dct}
```

Comment: Thanks, works indeed. I also want to keep the keys in the list, how can I do this?

Comment: @Thomma added. ;

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) in list comprehension:

```
first_thirty_per_key = [value[:30] for value in my_dict.values()]
```

To keep the keys (and hence keep the dictionary), use a dictionary comprehension with [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
my_dict_shortened = {key: value[:30] for key, value in my_dict.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks, works indeed. I also want to keep the keys in the list, how can I do this?